# How add relative route with useRoutes and react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to make a router **Info** relative to **Main**, that is, that Main is accessible under the path `/main` while Info under the path `/main/acc/update`
Is it possible to do it with **useRoutes** or should I do it as a separate path?

**Example:**

```
 useRoutes([
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <Base />,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/',
          element: <SomeElement />,
        },
        {
          path: 'main/*',
          element: (
            <>
              <Main />
              <Outlet />
            </>
          ),
          children: [
            {
              path: 'acc/update',
              element: <Info />,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ])
```

Comment: I dont get your question, you get some error??

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
  {
          path: 'main/*',
          element: (
            <PrivateRoute>
              <Outlet />
            </PrivateRoute>
          ),
          children: [
            { index: true, element: <Main /> },
            { path: 'acc/update', element: <Info /> },
          ],
        },
```